# How to make another virtual host for another project in ec2 aws for deploying laravel

Tags: php, linux, amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-ec2

I am subscribed for free to amazon aws ec2. I can only get one ec2 instance but I got two laravel projects. I can already access the first project that i put in `/var/www/html/GuidanceExam-Scheduler` but I have another project and the problem is when i access the ip or the public dns of my ec2, the one that will appear is the first one.

Here is my `000-default.conf` in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        #ServerName www.example.com
        RewriteEngine on
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/GuidanceExam-Scheduler/public

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

          <Directory "/var/www/html/GuidanceExam-Scheduler/public">
                AllowOverride all
                Require all granted
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
          </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Is it possible to add another virtual host? But my problem is I am using only one IP. Need some help on this since im new to amazon.

The `GuidanceExam-Scheduler` is my first project that i can already access using the ip or the public dns in ec2, but I already cloned my another project in `var/www/html/capstoneproject`, projectname = `capstoneproject` .

In my `var/www/html/` I got two projects

```
GuidanceExam-Scheduler   - I can access using IP or Public DNS which is http://54.254.162.165/
capstoneproject          - Dont know how to access.
```

How can I make my Ip which is `http://54.254.162.165/` to make a virtual host or to view my second project. Is that possible? I only have 1 IP/Public DNS in a ec2 instance free tier.

Comment: Enable another port then make new 'VirtualHost'

Comment: can you teach me how could i do it @vadivela

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out. In my `000-default.conf` I have pointed the IP to the specific project which is `GuidanceExam-Scheduler` which is `/var/www/html/GuidanceExam-Scheduler/public`. So basically if i will change it to `/var/www/html/` and when I have two projects. I can access them in my IP like `183.123.123/GuidanceExam-Scheduler/public` and `183.123.123/Project2/public`